# Can any Java pro's point me on how to connect to secure LDAP server?

Tags: java, ldap, spring-ldap

I have been unable to find a resource on this matter. I have the URL and user/password.

Please help.

Comment: [Spring LDAP - Reference Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ldap/docs/1.3.x/reference/html/)

Comment: well start with http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=spring+ldap :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the JNDI Tutorial.  In short you put the Principal and Credentials into a environment hash and pass that through to the server in a "bind" operation to create the context.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/ldap.html